# Redis Database Dumps in a Web Interface?

Tags: redis

Is there a utility out there that prettyfies entire redis databases? I'd like to see everything in there in a formatted view.

I can write my own, I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already wrote a little utility to do this. It can be found here
http://github.com/colummcgaley/phpMyRedis

It is still in development but it does do the basic functions, but you could also do `redis-cli key *`